# i have this issue "Workspace.hugyuihjoih.LocalScript:4: attempt to index nil with 'Destroy'"

Tags: lua, roblox

```lua
local BackPack = game.Players.LocalPlayer.Backpack
game.Players.LocalPlayer.leaderstats.Strength.Changed:Connect(function()
    if game.Players.LocalPlayer.leaderstats.Strength.Value >= 30 and game.StarterPack.Weight.Equipped then
    game.Players.LocalPlayer.Character:FindFirstChild("Weight"):Destroy()
    local DoubleWeight = game.ReplicatedStorage.Tools.DoubleWeight:Clone()
    DoubleWeight.Parent = BackPack
    if game.StarterPack.Weight.Unequipped and game.Players.LocalPlayer.leaderstats.Strength.Value >= 30 then
        BackPack:FindFirstChild("Weight"):Destroy()
    end         
  end
end)
```

Answer (score 0):

`game.Players.LocalPlayer.Character:FindFirstChild("Weight")` returns a nil value, hence you may not index it with `Destroy` as in `game.Players.LocalPlayer.Character:FindFirstChild("Weight"):Destroy()`

You need to check wether that value exists befor you attempt to index it.

Comment: everything is working fine even when this error shows up i just think its annoying and it can bother someone